# Convert rows into column in SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a user defined function which parses strings. My string looks like `1@>@100`. So when I call my function, it returns three records with 1, > and 100. I need to insert these results into a temp table as columns.

My temporary table has three columns.

OR YOU CAN CONSIDER THAT I HAVE TEMP TABLE (table have only one column) WITH 3 ROWS AND I NEED TO CONVERT RESULT TO 3 COLUMN.

so select * from #tmptable will give me 3 rows but i need to display all 3 rows as column.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you just asking for the SQL to insert the values?

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm misunderstanding the question:

INSERT INTO *tablename* VALUES (1, '>', 100);

Unless the first and third columns are strings, then you would put single quotes around them too.

Comment: 1 > 100 as 3 rows which i need to insert into temp table as column

Comment: Interesting... the insert statement above should insert those three values as a single column properly, but you'll still have the three rows somewhere else which will need to be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding an identity to your temp table and performing a PIVOT:

```
declare @t table(id int identity(1,1), strfrag varchar(8))
insert into @t values
('1'), ('>'), ('100');

select [1],[2],[3] from @t
pivot (
    max(strfrag)
    for id in ([1],[2],[3])
) as pt;
```

Result:

```
1        2        3
-------- -------- --------
1        >        100
```

Comment: You copied and pasted exactly? I just pasted the above into SQL 2008 and got no error. In 2005 the only thing I had to change was the insert into part. But no pivot errors.